# Is there a way to match ActiveRecord SQL logs to line numbers in my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, logging

In development, Rails with automatically log all your ActiveRecord queries.

Is there a way, or a gem, or a tool that somehow can give me the query logs PLUS where in my code that query originated in (for example, the line in the view during iteration)?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [NewRelic gem](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm) in development mode for this.

Comment: Interesting...ok I'll try it and let you know how it goes!